# Proving a hyperboloid of sheet one is defined contained in two lines

Tags: differential-geometry

[I've included jpegs of the question and answer below]

I am using Pressley's Intro to Differential Geometry and trying to solve this proof using the guided solution in the back of the book.  I am however having trouble figuring out what $L_\theta$ actually is. Like which line they are referring to because no line is named as such in the question. Also how they figured to use the point $(\sin(2\theta),-\cos(2\theta),0) $ and its parallel vector for that matter. I've been puzzling at this a while any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question:
[image: Question]

Partially Guided Solution in back of text:
[image]

Comment: Have you seen enough pictures in the subject, like e.g. on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid?